# How to make program loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to allow my program to have another name input   indefinitely. Right now, if you'd want to look up another name, you'd need to restart the entire program. This program calculates employee net pay value. All employees have a standard $45 deduction from their checks.
If an employee does not earn enough to cover the deduction, an error is displayed.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
  // Declare variables
  string name;
  int hours;
  int DEDUCTION = 45;
  int gross;
  int net;
  int rate;
  string EOFNAME = "quit";
  char again = 'Y';

  // Declare input items
  cout << "Enter first name or " << EOFNAME << " to quit ";
  cin >> name;
  if (name == EOFNAME) {
    cout << "End of program ";
    return 0;
  } else {
    cout << "Enter hours worked for " << name << endl;
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "Enter hourly rate for " << name << endl;
    cin >> rate;
    gross = hours * rate;
    net = gross - DEDUCTION;
  }
  do {
    cout << "Net pay for " << name << " is " << net << endl;
    break;
  } while (net > 0);

  {
    if (net < 0)
      cout << "Deductions not covered. Net is 0." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
} // end of main
```

Comment: You already use `while`. You should know how to loop.

Comment: Use a `for`, `while` or `do` loop (or even a `label:` + a `goto` - *not* recommended) if you want a loop in your program.

Comment: @DimChtz I really don't know how to do much. This is the first program I've ever written.

Comment: Please start with a tutorial for the language you are trying to learn, I don't think this forum is the right place for this.

Comment: [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) may be an option as well.

Comment: @joanis Prefer to push people toward [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) unless you have a tutorial in mind. The number of indifferent and outright harmful tutorials dwarf the number of tutorials that will make a person a better programmer. Until that person knows enough about the language and its idioms to be able to tell good from bad, odds are too high they will find bad.

Comment: @user4581301 good point, that's a more reliable source of good language introductions. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you need to implement a [main loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). Might I suggest the following:

First, take everything you have in `main()` and put it in another function, something like:

```
void processEmployeeDeductions()
{
  // All the code currently in main()
}
```

Then start with an infinite-loop in `main()` that just calls the function repeatedly:

```
int main()
{
  while(1) // Loop forever!
  {
    processEmployeeDeductions();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When your code becomes more sophisticated, you will be able to change the conditional of the loop to trigger on specific events (such as a handler `SIGINT` setting a flag to end the loop).